# How to ssh using python and kerberos root principle?

Tags: python, ssh, kerberos, paramiko

I am writing a python script to ssh into a server and transfer some files to a location. I tried with paramiko library but its authenticating with my personal userid and password. I want to transfer different files on diiferent server as root, for that i need passwordless authentication. Please suggest any way to connect to different servers as root.

Comment: There's nothing like *"passwordless authentication"*. Do you mean *"public key authentication"*?

Comment: I mean i want to authenticate using kerberos authentication

Comment: Duh - `root` is an _implicit_ Linux account, not the kind of account you can define in a Kerberos KDC... Unless you try a complicated workaround i.e. define a SPN for a dummy "root" service for every machine, and define a mapping rule in SSSD to match it to `root` - but there might be nasty side effects, usually root is explicitely excluded from external auth

Comment: Better use Kerberos on a sudoer "service account".

Answer (score 0):

I do this on the corporate LAN between servers with Paramiko as a root user. However you (or Ops) will have to install root keys for passwordless SSH:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/STAV45/com.ibm.sonas.doc/mng_ssh_key.html

After doing this your Paramiko code:

```
client.connect(hostname, port=port, username=username, password=password)
```

will become:

```
client.connect(hostname, port=port, "root")
```

Comment: The way its configured in our infrastructure is user home directories are automounted from autofs and root user access is set up using kerberos root principle. so when i use client.connect(hostname, port=port, "root") it tries to log in as root but does not authenticate using kerberos root principle.

Comment: That's okay... same where I  am. If you su - to root on one machine, and then SSH to another machine, does it prompt for a password or does it log you in as root?

Comment: so when i log into a server i log into with my personal id. and after that i do kinit which grants me a ticket. after that i do ksu which gives me root access to the system. When i do ssh to another machine, it does not ask me for password.